# Subversion Keyword for Filename

Tags: svn, documentation, repository, javadoc

## Background

Customer requests that all source files include the following in the header:

```
File: filename.ext
```

## Problem

As far as I can tell, Subversion offers the following [keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html):

- Id
- Rev
- Revision
- Date
- LastChangedDate
- LastChangedRevision
- Author
- LastChangedBy
- HeadURL
- URL

Of those keywords that contain the filename, they all contain *more* information than the filename.

## Question

Short of writing a [script hook](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/check-mime-type.pl), what Subversion keyword contains only the filename and nothing else but the file's name and extension (no path, no URL, no author, no revision, etc.)?

To be clear, if the file was named "MyFile.java", then I'd like to see the following automatically added to the header:

```
/**
 * File: $File:: MyFile.java$
 * ... other keywords ...
 */
```

Comment: The problem is that you were actually reading outdated documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SVN is 1.8+, you can define and use custom keywords (see `svn help ps`). Substitution pattern `%b` is that you want:

```
>svn pl -v data.txt
Properties on 'data.txt':
  svn:keywords
    File=%b
```

Content of `data.txt` in repo, without keyword expansion (hard to get today)

```
//$File$

Data
```

Content of `data.txt` in Working Copy

```
// $File: data.txt $

Data
```

And full repository tree

```
>svn ls -R
Data/
Data/Collection/
Data/Collection/data.txt
```

HTH